# How to reset Security Token of API Only User?

Tags: api, integration, user-record, security-token

How to reset Security Token of API Only User ?

I created a new user in salesforce exclusively for integration purpose. Got the welcome email,Verified Account and changed password.

Prior to this, I created a Profile 'API Only' and assigned this User to the Profile.
'API Only User'  and 'API Enabled' is checked.

I need the security token for this user. However when I go to the User record, and Login as this user, under personal settings, I do not see the option to 'Reset Security Token'

Comment: I followed those instructions before posting, however i do not see he security token.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. The IP ranges on the profile assigned to the User has this range 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 As a result, the User record did not have the option to 'Reset Security Token'

Deleted the entry for this range, and was able to see the 'Reset Security Token'